# Algorithm for connecting all nodes in one layer to all nodes in the next layer

Tags: c#, algorithm, neural-network, nodes

I am trying to write a NeuralNet using back Propagation using this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkwX7FkLfug tutorial.

I am trying to do it in C# and am changing some of the details.

The main difference between his and mine is that I don't know how many neurons are going to be on each node from the beginning.  Here is how my API is going to work in code.

```
class main
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<bool> testData = new List<bool>() {true};
        System.Console.WriteLine("In MAIN! \n");
        int inputNeurons = 64;
        int outputNeurons = 2;

        double eta   =  0.1; // 0.0..1.0    training rate
        double alpha =  0.5; // 0.0..n      momentum

        NeuralNet neuralNet = new NeuralNet(eta, alpha);
        // order matters, first layer is for input, last layer is for output
        neuralNet.AddLayer(inputNeurons);   // input layer
                                            // multiple hidden layers could go here
        neuralNet.AddLayer(outputNeurons);  // output Layer
        neuralNet.MakeConnections();

        neuralNet.Train(testData);

        neuralNet.GetResults();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of my code for the NeuralNet, some of it is pseudo code or just print statements right now while I try and get the connections working.

```
namespace NeuralNetJO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }

    public class NeuralNet
    {
        public NeuralNet(double newEta, double newAlpha)
        {
            numLayers = -1; // numLayers tracks how many layers of neurons the neural net has
            eta = newEta;
            alpha = newAlpha;
        }

        /**
        *   GetResults()
        *       returns array of results and weights
        */
        public void GetResults()
        {
            foreach (Layer l in n_layer)
            {
                foreach (Neuron n in l.n_neurons)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        public void MakeConnections()
        {
            // For each layer
            if (numLayers > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n_layer.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n_layer[i].n_neurons.Count; j++)
                    {
                        //For each Node in Layer that isn't final layer, connect it to every node in the next layer

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void FeedForward(List<int> inputVals)
        {

        }

        public void BackProp(List<int> targetVals)
        {

        }

        public void AddLayer(int numNeurons)
        {
            numLayers++;
            if (numLayers > 0) //If first layer
            {
                Layer layer = new Layer(numNeurons, numLayers, n_layer[numLayers - 1]);
                n_layer.Add(layer);
            }
            else
            {
                Layer layer = new Layer(numNeurons, numLayers);
                n_layer.Add(layer);
            }
        }

        public void Train(List<bool> testData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Training...");
            if (testData[0] == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t False");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t True");
            }
        }



        //-------------- Member Variables --------------//

        private List<Layer> n_layer = new List<Layer>(); // List of layers, layers are comprised of Neurons
        private int numLayers;
        double eta;
        double alpha;
    }


    public class Layer
    {
        // mumLayer is for debug purposes only
        public Layer(int numNeurons, int numLayer, Layer prevLayer = null) 
        {
            myLayer = numLayer;
            for (int i = 0; i <= numNeurons; ++i) // Add a bias Neuron
            {
                System.Console.Write(i + ": "); // Show line number for accurate Neuron count
                Neuron neuron = new Neuron(i);

                Console.WriteLine(" in layer #" + numLayer);
                n_neurons.Add(neuron);
            }

            if (prevLayer != null)
            {
                foreach (Neuron n in prevLayer)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        public List<Neuron> n_neurons = new List<Neuron>();
        int myLayer;
    }

    /**
    *   Neuron is a class that holds public information about Neurons
    *   This include weights, value, input and output locations.
    */
    public class Neuron
    {
        public Neuron(int index) // Constructor
        {
            myIndex = index;
            System.Console.Write("Creating Neuron " + myIndex);
        }



        private double transferFunction(double x)
        {
            return x;
        }

        private double transferFunctionDerivative(double x)
        {
            return x;
        }

        double randomWeight()
        {
            // set weights random
            Random r = new Random(0);
            return r.NextDouble() * 2 - 1.0;
        }

        public double Value { get; set; }   // Output value
        List<Connection> outPutWeights;     // Fpr each connection for the layer to the right
        public int numOutputs { set; get; } // This will be set when numLayers > 0;
        int myIndex;
        double eta;     // training rate
        double alpha;   // momentum
        double gradient;

        private double sumDOW(Layer nextLayer)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class Connection
    {
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public double DeltaWeight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the tutorial, he gives each neuron the number of neurons in the next layer.  In my code, I can't do that because I am adding one layer at a time.  The first layer added will be the input layer, the second through n-1 layers are for hidden layers and the final layer is the output layer.

I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around a good algorithm that can loop through each neuron in the first layer and link them to each neuron in the second and so forth.  I am assuming it will need to be recursive and use my 'numLayers' variable in some way.

As you can see in my usage code I make the call `neuralNet.MakeConnections()`, I am open to the idea of adding the connections as I add additional layers instead; if anyone can see a good place to do it that way.

That was my original idea but when I got stuck I drew myself a picture and decided that it might be simpler to do it in this function instead.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Take care with your use of `numLayers`.  You start it at `-1` even though `n_layer.Count==0`.  Then you use it to decide if this is your first layer or not.  Why not just use `if(n_layer.Count==0) ...` itself to decide when you are adding the first layer?

Answer (score 1):

re: `I am assuming it will need to be recursive`

Not at all. Also no essential need for the extra variable `numLayers`, you already know how many layers you have added with `n_layers.Count`.

```
// in class NeuralNet
public void MakeConnections()
{
  // start at input layer, stop at last hidden layer
  for(int i=0; i<(n_layer.Count()-1); ++i)
  {
    Layer thisLayer = n_layer[i];   // only for typing convenience
    Layer nextLayer = n_layer[i+1];
    for(int n1=0; n1<thisLayer.n_neurons.Count(); ++n1)
    {
      Neuron thisNeuron = thisLayer.n_neurons[n1];
      for(int n2=0; n2<nextLayer.n_neurons.Count(); ++n2)
      {
        thisNeuron.outPutWeights.Add(
          new Connection(randomWeight(),randomWeight());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you prefer to add these connections when you add the layers, then it might look something like this:

```
// in class NeuralNet
public void AddLayer(int numNeurons)
{
  Layer layer = new Layer(numNeurons,
                          n_layers.Count(),
                          (n_layers.Count > 0)
                            ? n_layer[n_layers.Count-1]
                            : null);
  n_layers.Add(layer);
}
```

and

```
// in class Layer
public Layer(int numNeurons,
             int numLayer,
             Layer prevLayer = null)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= numNeurons; ++i)
  {
    Neuron neuron = new Neuron(i);
    n_neurons.Add( neuron );
  }
  if (prevLayer != null)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<prevLayer.n_neurons.Count(); ++i)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<n_neurons.Count(); ++j)
      {
        prevLayer.n_neurons[i].outputWeights.Add(
          new Connection(randomWeight(), randomWeight() ) );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is, of course, no need to make the connections in both styles.  You'd have double connections that way.  Just either do them all at once with `MakeConnections` or do them on the fly.